# Video splitting tool

Tags: video, video-editing

I'm using [video2x](https://github.com/k4yt3x/video2x) for a hobby project, and /i wanted to convert several video files to higher resolution. I was initially impressed with the results I've got for a very short video file (less than a minute), but even for 10min video, the disk space required by this tool is immense (like 4800 x original video size). And the lack of disk space crashes my computer and goes all the the way back to the start.

This seems solvable if I could split the starting video into smaller files (less than a minute per video), the applied the tool in a batch (as the large files are deleted once every individual video is finished) and re-joined the upscaled split parts with some tool.

Is there a software that does this? It is important to split the video files into smaller video files, not into smaller zip files or similar. Many tools allow splitting manually, but this gets cumbersome if I need to split one video into 60 files.

PS: Something that splits in equal files sizes would be great, but if it could cut between scenes, that would be even better.

PS2: Ultra Video Splitter seems to do it, but it's paid, and does not join files later. Bandicut does what I need but is also paid.

Comment: Have you tried a video editing tool? Among free ones, for example, Olive, OpenShot, VSDC Free Video Editor, DaVinci Resolve, etc. Ideally, you want something that can do direct stream copy. I had heard of one a long time ago, but I don't remember what it was called. Next best option would be to buy a new hard drive (external drive?) I know how frustrating it gets when it's almost done and then crashes...

Comment: I've already cleared up 700gb of space for converting 20min videos and it crashed all the same, so the (cost+risk)/benefit ratio for a new drive is not so great. I haven't tried any of these tools because I've never used any of them, and it I would need something that would break a 20 min video into 30 sec chunks at once (preferably with no piece-by-piece manual action), this seems hard to find, hence why I'm trying my luck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could install [python](https://www.python.org/) and [MoviePy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) (which installs and uses [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/)) and use that to split your file into chunks *(note that I am using [iPython](https://ipython.org/) in the example below).*

[image: Example]

Obviously if you are doing a lot of files you can make this into a script rather than using it interactively.

### The good news

All of the tools above are:

- **Free** gratis & open source
- **Cross Platform** will work on Windows, OS-X & Linux.
- **Small** (will not take up a huge amount of your hard drive).
- You could even change it so that it waits after each file for you to tell it that you have processed it and then move on to the next.
- You can use the same tools to re-assemble the fragments into a single file.
- There is a lot more that you can do once you get into it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think it's about time I ditch my teenage habit of searching "free software to ..." and replace with "python module to ...".

Comment: However, I've had a very bad experience trying to join the files later, partially because they were in .mkv format. So I actually used [mkvtoolnix](https://mkvtoolnix.download/downloads.html) to merge the files.